# Powershell verb for "did something succeed

Tags: powershell

So I looked over [approved verbs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714428(v=vs.85).aspx) for powershell commands from Microsoft and I still don't know what would be the best verb for a function that returns whether something succeed.

Specifically I am writing a powershell function that returns true or false whether a given TFS build succeeded or not.

How about this?

> Get-IsBuildSuccess

Comment: How about `Assert-BuildStatus` with a `-Success` parameter with a default value of `$true`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the verb Test, like Test-Path.
And then modify the rest to suit the verb. BuildStatus as suggested sounds good.